# Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading: 'filter')

Tags: angular, typescript

```
findLoads(){
if(this.loggedInUser.userFullySetupFlag === 0 || this.loggedInUser.businessFullySetupFlag === 0){
  swal(
    'Incomplete Profile',
    'To find loads and bid, all the details inside User Profile (My Profile) and Business Profile (My Business) must be completed.',
    'error'
) 
return;
}

this.shipmentService.filterLoads(this.currentLoadBoardSearch).subscribe(responseObj =>{
  responseObj.searchResults = responseObj.searchResults.filter(function(value, index, arr){return value.loadNumber <= responseObj.loadNumber;});
  this.filteredLoads = responseObj.searchResults;
  console.log("Load Results:", responseObj);
  
});
this.spinner.hide();}
```

The project consist many files which I am unable to show here. But kindly help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Looks like your `responseObj.searchResults` is undefined. Perhaps the structure of the response object is a different one. Try logging it to the console to see what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `responseObj.searchResults` is `undefined` that's why throwing error when apply filter on it.
To avoid this, just use `safe operator (?)` introduced in `ES2020`

Try below code:

```
this.shipmentService.filterLoads(this.currentLoadBoardSearch).subscribe(responseObj =>{
  responseObj.searchResults = responseObj?.searchResults?.filter(function(value, index, arr){return value?.loadNumber <= responseObj?.loadNumber;});
  this.filteredLoads = responseObj?.searchResults;
  console.log("Load Results:", responseObj);
  
});
```

Comment: It worked to me

`responseObj.searchResult = (responseObj.searchResult || []).filter(function(value, index, arr){return value.loadNumber <= responseObj.loadNumber;});`